# Why might Let's Encrypt issue a certificate not valid for another hour or so?

Tags: lets-encrypt

I'm using an open source Let's Encrypt tool, and it has worked for years on some servers. On one, in the US, the certificate is being found not valid because it is "not valid yet". The "Valid From" appears reasonable, perhaps a few hours off, but UTC would account for that.

I am suspecting that the problem is in the client validation, but welcome any thoughts on the specifics of why that might be so we can dig deeper.

Answer (score 0):

Without more information I can't be certain, but the most likely cause is that the server's clock is off by a few hours. If you have control over this server, make sure that it is properly syncing with a networked time server. This is usually done through [NTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Time_Protocol).

Comment: Thanks - do you know what time zone the "valid from" uses? Is it UTC, or is it somehow related to the clock on the requesting server?

Comment: Time stamps have no time zone associated with them. Each timestamp is simply a number representing the number of micro, milli, or seconds from the start of the unix epoch. Dates do have time zones and they are obviously location specific. Cert validation uses the difference between two timestamps and so is independent of time zone.

Answer (score 0):

For the record, it was the web server that was loading the certificate, that was not taking the time zone into account. Due to the offset from UTC, it was thinking the certificate hadn't started yet.